# read the last X number of lines in array vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am using the code below but it gives me the first 10 lines of the array. i cant figure out how to get the *last* 10 lines of the array.

```
        Dim t_low As String

        Dim l_low() As String = low.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)


        For c As Integer = 0 To l_low.Length - 1
            If c <= 10 - 1 Then
                t_low = t_low & l_low(c) & ","
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(t_low)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim t_low_1 As String = ""
Dim t_low_2 As String = ""

Dim l_low() As String = low.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For i As Integer = l_low.Length - 1 To l_low.Length - 10 Step -1
    t_low_1 = t_low_1 & l_low(i) & IIf(i <> l_low.Length - 10, ",", "")
    t_low_2 = l_low(i) & IIf(i <> l_low.Length - 1, ",", "") & t_low_2
Next i

MsgBox(t_low_1)
MsgBox(t_low_2)
```

I used two variabile (`t_low_1` and `t_low_2`) because I don't understand the order you want to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim t_low As String

    Dim l_low() As String = low.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Array.Reverse(l_low)

    For c As Integer = 0 To 9            
        t_low = t_low & l_low(c) & ","            
    Next
    MsgBox(t_low)
```

Comment: It's either this or using Step -1 in conjunction with starting c at l_low.Length-1.

Comment: dhaval, thanks for the reply -- that gives me 10 records 10 from the bottom of the list, not the last 10

Comment: @user2835653   so that is what you want right ?? you want last 10 lines from the array ?? what is the difference between last 10 and bottom 10 ??

Comment: the data is (example) "111111111122222222223333333333" the last 10 is "3333333333" the first 10 is "1111111111" but your code results in "2222222222" -- so i am getting only 10 records, which is good, but it is stopping 10 from the bottom of the list, or said another way, 10 from the last record -- thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user2835653 can you please put this example in question itself ??

Answer (score 0):

I have an array(test) with some number of items.  This code concatenates the first and last 10 items, separated by commas.

```
    Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    If test.Length >= 10 Then
        'first 10
        For c As Integer = 0 To 9
            s.Append(test(c) & ",")
        Next
        'last 10
        For c As Integer = test.Length - 10 To test.Length - 1
            s.Append(test(c) & ",")
        Next
        s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1) 'remove trailing comma
        Debug.WriteLine(s.ToString)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
Dim l_low() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"}
Dim l_low2() As String = l_low.Skip(Math.Max(0, l_low.Length - 10)).Take(10).ToArray
```

You can then join elements of `l_low2` together separated by a comma using [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).